# Disable MacBook screen turn off at locked screen

Tags: display, mojave, sleep-wake

Is it possible to prevent OSX from turning off displays when on the lockscreen? I'll lock my MBP with 2 external monitors, leave for 2-3 minutes, and come back and the monitor will be off. It then takes a bit of time for them to all come back on. I've tried Caffeine but it only appears to work when unlocked.

Comment: What models are your external monitors?

Comment: Dell SE27H & ASUS PB278 each connected through HDMI with a USB-C dongle. The MacBook screen also turns off so it seems not to be monitor related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dug through Console and found it appeared to be checking for `preventIdleDisplaySleep` boolean. Searching on Github I found HammerSpoon which has a module which can set this via lua scripting. I installed HammerSpoon and added this to `~/.hammerspoon/init.lua` and it prevented the sleeping issues

```lua
require "hs.caffeinate"
require "hs.hotkey"

hs.caffeinate.set("displayIdle", true, false)
hs.caffeinate.set("systemIdle", true, false)
hs.caffeinate.set("system", true, false)

hs.hotkey.bind({"cmd"}, "l", function()
  hs.caffeinate.fastUserSwitch()
end)
```

(The hotkey bind to simulate Windows/Linux screen locking behavior)

https://github.com/Hammerspoon/hammerspoon

Answer (score 5):

There is a free and open-source tool named **KeepingYouAwake** that can be used as per your requirements.

Having KeepingYouAwake activated will prevent the screen from turning off when lock screen mode is activated.

[Download the latest version here.](https://github.com/newmarcel/KeepingYouAwake/releases)

or install it via cask:

```
brew install keepingyouawake --cask
```

This utility will not harm your Mac because it is based on an official command-line tool by Apple. BUT I cannot guarantee anything, so use this tool AT YOUR OWN RISK.

Comment: This didn't work for me either

Answer (score 2):

Settings > Power Management has the options that puts the display to sleep after some time.

It has two independent settings to be used if connected to a power source or using battery only.

Tweak these settings as per your requirement.

Comment: These don't seem to apply to the lock/login screen. I have mine set to 1hr for both and the Mac still turns the display off minutes after locking (although it works correctly when leaving it unlocked)

Comment: Are you using any screen saver?

Comment: It's left at the default settings of starting after 20 minutes. It seems to work if I leave it unlocked but I've never seen it start on the lock screen

Answer (score 1):

Open Terminal and run the following:

```
caffeinate &
```

This will keep your display on until `caffeinate` is killed (you can quit Terminal if you want).

To disable `caffeinate`, run this in Terminal:

```
killall caffeinate
```

Hope this does the trick for you

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution without external software is use caffenaite:

```
caffeinate -d -w 1
```

Parameters:

- `-d  Create an assertion to prevent the display from sleeping.`
- `-w  Waits for the process with the specified pid to exit. With pid 1 is waiting for main launchd process, which always exists.`

If you do not want to run it manually use lauchd. Create file `~/Library/LaunchAgents/local.caffeinate.plist`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>local.caffeinate</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>sh</string>
        <string>-c</string>
        <!-- Prevent external display from sleeping. -->
        <string>caffeinate -d -w 1</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```